# in MVC, how to verify reliability of submitted form hidden fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-fields, sensitive-data

In mvc, when submitted to a controller, how can I verify that a user hasn't maliciously changed readonly hidden form fields?

Answer (score 2):

When displaying the form fields render a hidden field that contains a hash for the displayed values.

When receiving the post request hash the received data again and compare this hash to the value of the hidden field.

Comment: As more people suggest, I realize it may be the right thing to do.. Can you link to some info regarding this system?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757419/check-if-the-user-changed-data

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of:

1. Encrypt the fields when displaying them, then decrypt server side and use the value
2. Don't store sensitive information in hidden fields and instead store them in the session (recommended)

Comment: tnks. sessions considered and disqualified, because it reveals a different kind of data disruption threat. For ex, in case of using more than one browser at a time.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when using more than one browser at a time? If you're using more than one browser at a time you can still store things in the session.

Comment: Sure I can. By saying more than one I mean through another tab, or even a new browser window. consider the following scenario: in order to construct an entity with quite a lot of information, I need to performe a sequence of forms submitting. Every time I return a view from a controller, I need to pass some id's about the not yet established entity. If you're working with more than one browser tab, they both pass the same session...

Comment: Of course, by saying "If you're working with more than one browser tab" I mean on two different entities ...